# Allocate Dates to Week IDs

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

I have a java program that runs on a machine with no system-clock. I want to manage some date-related data: I save them in a DAY class with DAY-ID ("YYYYMMDD") and variables YEAR, MONTH, DAY,... I want to sum up these DAYs into WEEKs. These WEEKs need a WEEK-ID as well, maybe like "YYYY"+number .. or DAY-ID from the first day (monday).

How do I determine which DAYs go into which WEEK without hardcoding a whole year of dates, if i want to take 28.-31. day months into account?
Further: How do i determine which workday (Monday-Friday) is a DAY?

Is there a Calender Class or something like that, where I can get() these information?

Comment: You can use [joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Comment: When does you week number start.  Is the first monday always week 1 or could it be week 2? Does a week start on a Saturday, Sunday or Monday?

Comment: Yes, there is a [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class where you can [get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)) these informations. Just google it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @sp00m mentioned it: you can use a [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 4);
int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

you can get a lot parameter from the Calendar

Answer (score 0):

There is an international standard for handling what is seems you are trying to do: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The standard defines each week in a year, each day of week (Monday=1, Sunday=7), how to handle weeks overlapping end of year, each day of year (2013-352), and more.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library is meant to replace the troublesome java.util.Date/Calendar classes. Joda-Time follows ISO 8601 by default.